# How to configure Nginx to serve https only for wordpress on Azure App Service

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx, service, azure-web-app-service

I been dealing with Azure App service to serve wordpress is using nginx,
here is the current nginx config that i am using but it gives me multiple " was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script" errors , any ideas how to solve this?

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  server.com; 
    port_in_redirect off;
    
    access_log   /home/data/access.log;
    error_log    /home/data/error.log;




    # Custom to allow large file uploads
    
    client_max_body_size 256M;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args =404;
    }
    

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
            #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

}
```

i tried multiple configs from the page of nginx and wordpress. (none worked exactly many of the give me error 404 and too many redirects.

Comment: Not sure why would you want to go to the trouble of doing this. In the Portal, set your Web App to accept HTTPS only. Note that App Service does TLS termination.

Comment: is already set to only accept https,

the main issue is when installing wordpress it doesnt load all objects due "This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." so this is why i am trying to fix

Comment: thanks for the link , i tried that, but that doesn't work neither , it kinda odd that if you setup wordpress as app service directly it works , but i you wanna do it step by step it doesn't 

it gives many redirects issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

added this to wp config plus the part on nginx to make it work on azure app service

Comment: Hello Adan, I was able to reproduce this issue and added the block of code above to wp-config-sample.php file, and it didnt work. Can you help with any config changes you might have made too? I would like to send my file content to you as well if that will help

Comment: Thank you Adan for assisting me off here. I can confirm that these config changes were in fact the correct solution. Cheers.